# call different class functions or a combo of class functions depending on arg in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a subparser named `app01`. It has two arguments `--delete-user`, and `--delete-hash`. I've set the default function to call the function `check_app`

the `check_app` function is something like this:

```
def check_app(args):
    a = App()
    if args.user:
        # run function01 from App() class to delete user account
    elif args.hash:
        # run function02 from App() class delete user hash
    else:
        # run both functions to delete user and hash
```

How do i get that to work without having to add both function01 and function02 into the else block. Or is that the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think what code you have is decent.**

**If you want what you want this for purely aesthetic reasons, let me warn you that the code maintainability will drop substantially.** You can see the answer given by Ronan B already seems pretty confusing and if you're the person trying to understand it, it feels like too much work to decipher.

But if you still want me to titillate your senses, I may as well suggest a simpler version:

```
def check_app(args):
    a = App()
    if not args.user:
        # run #02    < note #2
    if not args.hash:
        # run #01    < note #1
```

This is of course assuming that **if both functions #1 and #2 need to run, no arguments are given**, instead of both arguments being given, as is typically intuitive.

Comment: not purely for aesthetic reasons, but i thought listing both functions again in the else block would not be very DRY. Was trying to find a way to make it readable without repeating same code. I tested both suggestions and they both work but i think yours is a bit easier to read.